# Android: NavigationView TextColor

Tags: android, android-navigationview

Pictures say more than words:

[image: Right]

This should be the right appearance..
But I get this:
[image: Wrong]

This is my code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/Black"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/White"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/White"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer" />
```

How can I solve this?

Here is my menu-xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/drawerFullName"
            android:icon="@drawable/fullnamemale"
            android:title="@string/full_name" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/drawerAge"
            android:icon="@drawable/age"
            android:title="@string/age" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/drawerAbout"
            android:icon="@drawable/about"
            android:title="@string/about_user_in_20_letters" />
        <item android:title="@string/personalize">
            <menu>
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/drawerChangeTheme"
                    android:icon="@drawable/changetheme"
                    android:title="@string/change_your_theme" />
            </menu>
        </item>
        <item android:title="@string/user_settings">
            <menu>
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/drawerLogout"
                    android:icon="@drawable/logout"
                    android:title="@string/logout" />
            </menu>
        </item>
    </group>
</menu>
```

Yes and the "headings" color isn't changing. It is still black..

To complete this, here is the navigation view with a white background, now you can see the headings:
[image]

Comment: What is your question exactly? If you want to change the textcolor use your line: `app:itemTextColor="@color/White"`

Comment: The question is, how can I set the text color of the element between "About you" and "Change your theme" to white. I have app:itemTextColor in my navigationview already..

Comment: You have to create a style for the NavigationView and override the "android:textColorSecondary" attribute and make it white (or whatever color do you need). Pay attention because this override change the icons' color too (but I think in your case it's ok).

Comment: "this override change the icons' color too" not true in my case extending from Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar, the color is only applied to the headers, not to each item or item icon.

Answer (score 6):

We can use **app:itemTextColor** & **app:itemIconTint** in **NavigationView** to change Text and icon color of navigation menu items.

```
 <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/drawer_menu_text"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/drawer_menu_text"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation_drawer">
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like your app is using light theme but you want your navigaiton view to be dark. This means you have to override the theme for the navigation view.

Here follows code which will allow you to fully customize text colors inside the navigation view:

#### res/color/primary_text.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- 38% white for disabled color per material design specs.
    <item
        android:color="#60ffffff"
        android:state_enabled="false"/>
    <!-- 100% white for primary text. -->
    <item android:color="#ffffffff"/>
</selector>
```

#### res/color/secondary_text.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- 38% white for disabled color per material design specs. -->
    <item
        android:color="#60ffffff"
        android:state_enabled="false"/>
    <!-- 70% white for secondary text. -->
    <item android:color="#b2ffffff"/>
</selector>
```

#### res/values/styles.xml

```
<style name="ThemeOverlay.MyApp.NavigationView" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
    <!-- This is the menu item text color. -->
    <item name="android:primaryTextColor">@color/primary_text</item>
    <!-- This is the menu header text color. -->
    <item name="android:secondaryTextColor">@color/secondary_text</item>
    <!-- This is the selected color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
</style>
```

#### res/layout/something.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/Black"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MyApp.NavigationView"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to supply style to NavigationView.

```
<style name="ApBaseDrawerNavigationMenuStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@null</item>
        <item name="android:color">@color/text_color</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_color</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/text_color</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/text_color</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/gray_shade_555555</item>
        <item name="android:background">#548893</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/text_color</item>
        <item name="android:colorControlHighlight">@color/text_color</item>
    </style>
```

Please set above properties in your style.
Hope this helps in future.

Comment: Why <item name="colorControlNormal">@null</item>?

Comment: android:colorPrimary doesn't change any text colors, you should add a description for what each entry is supposed to be.